# Named registrations in autofac

Tags: autofac

Is it possible to group components' registrations by name using [autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)?
For instance, the bellow code has two registrations for IDbContextProvider.
And I want WfcService to resolve only a named instance ("proxyless") of IDbContextProvider.
I'd like to use something like *DependsOnNamed("proxyless")* method to explicitly set a dependency on a set of named instances that have the same name.

I want the whole system to use the default implementation of IDbContextProvider while successors of IWfcService  should use their own named instances.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<DbContextProvider>().As<IDbContextProvider>().As<IDbContextProvider>();
builder.RegisterType<ProxyLessDbContextProvider>().Named<IDbContextProvider>("proxyless");

builder.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>();//depends on IDbContextProvider 
builder.RegisterType<BusinessService>().As<IBusinessService>();//depends on IRepository

builder.RegisterType<WfcService>().As<IWfcService>().DependsOnNamed("proxyless");//depends on IBusinessService

IContainer container = builder.Build();

var wcf = container.Resolve<IWfcService>(); // should depend on "proxyless" IDbContextProvider
```

Comment: Don't think you can do this, but perhaps you could use the "tag" functionality on lifetime scope and the InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(tag) method to accomplish this.

Comment: It seems it works now. The trick I've used is `AutofacHostFactory.Container = _container.BeginLifetimeScope(PersistanceRegistrationModule.ProxylessScope);`  So, each wcf service call instantiates an appropriate IDbContextProvider instance using its own tagged lifetime scope. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope "overrides" the default implementation and resolution from the "root" scope doesn't work

Comment: after a research I submitted a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=365)

Comment: To achieve mentioned behavior I create a separate scope and override the configuration in it `_container.BeginLifetimeScopee(innerBuilder => innerBuilder.RegisterType<IDbContextProvider>.....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate way to achieve described behavior is to use the separate scope with overridden registration. If you want to override a registration for WCF services you should

```
var _wcfScope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope(b=> 
{
    b.RegisterType<NewDbContextProvider>().As<DbContextProvider>();
    //put wcf services registration here because of the issue http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=365
});
AutofacHostFactory.Container = _wcfScope;
```